# C#でC++のDLLから文字列を受け取る

Tags: c#, c++

ご回答いただけると幸いです。

C++で文字列(英数字混在)をcharでreturnする関数を書き、
C#からその関数を利用し、文字列を受け取ろうと考えています。
調べてみたところ、C#から文字列を渡すような手順はあっても、
C++の方から戻す方法が見つからず、困り果てております。
どなたか、ご存知の方がいらっしゃれば、お教えいただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 6):

C/C++ で「関数が文字列を返す」というアクションは２つのパターンがあって
１．呼ばれる関数が `malloc()` 等で動的にメモリを取り、そこに文字列を格納する (`strdup`)
２．呼ぶ側の関数が固定長のバッファを取り、呼ばれる関数がそこに文字列を格納する (`snprintf`)
今回の事案はどっちでしょう。

後者であれば `StringBuilder` が使えます。これなら unsafe 不要で、エンコーディング変換も自動。

C++ 側

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall GetText(char* buf, size_t bufsize) {
    if (bufsize<4) return false
    buf[0]='a';
    buf[1]='\x82'; // 82a0 = CP932 の 'あ'
    buf[2]='\xa0';
    buf[3]='\0';
    return true;
}
```

C# 側

```
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern Boolean GetText(StringBuilder s, Int32 bufsize);

// CharSet.Ansi は OS の標準現地固有エンコーディングを UTF-16 に自動変換する指定
// 日本語 OS の場合 CP932 → UTF-16
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(256);
GetText(sb, sb.Capacity);
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // aあ
```

前者の場合 `malloc()` 系の結果をいつどうやって `free()` するかによって話が違い
C/C++ 側の仕様というか実装というかを見ないと答えが出せません。

Answer (score 4):

::CoTaskMemAllocで確保したメモリを使用すると.Net側でのGC対象とすることができるので
C++からC#への文字列の受け渡しは以下のリンク先のような実装にするとC#側の実装が楽になります。
https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/

C/C++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char*  __stdcall StringReturnAPI01()
{
    char szSampleString[] = "Hello World";
    ULONG ulSize = strlen(szSampleString) + sizeof(char);
    char* pszReturn = NULL;

    pszReturn = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(ulSize);
    // Copy the contents of szSampleString
    // to the memory pointed to by pszReturn.
    strcpy(pszReturn, szSampleString);
    // Return pszReturn.
    return pszReturn;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("<path to DLL>", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string StringReturnAPI01();

static void CallUsingStringAsReturnValue()
{
  string strReturn01 = StringReturnAPI01();
  Console.WriteLine("Returned string : " + strReturn01);
}
```

Comment: リンクが切れるかもしれないので、リンクの内容をご記入ください。

Answer (score 1):

C# で /unsafe コンパイルして byte* (ポインタ） を使うか
/unsafe を使わずに 領域を Pinned して そのアドレスを渡すかですね。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579446/how-can-i-pass-a-pointer-to-an-integer-in-c-sharp

の回答を ちょっと改良して引用すると

【unsafe使うパターン】

```
unsafe static void TestMethod()
{
    fixed (byte* buffer = new byte[4096])
    {
        int maxSize = buffer.Length;
        GetBuffer(buffer, ref maxSize);
    }
}
```

【unsafe使わないパターン】

```
byte[] buf = new byte[kBufSize];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buf, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
// 領域を確保して Pinned する事でアドレスが固定される。
IntPtr p = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
int size = buf.Length;
int ret = GetBuffer(p, ref size); // DLLImport された C++ の関数
handle.Free();
```

受け取った byte 配列は その文字列のエンコードに合わせて 文字に変換すればいいです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。お教えいただいた方法で無事目的を達成することができました。